# Sawtooth line style in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a linestyle / line-symbol combination that is essentially a cold front symbol:
[image: Triangles pointing up]

I've tried using the marker option for adding triangles with a rotation that matches the slope of the curve at every point, but it looks ugly and frankly doesn't work.

Is anyone aware of a way to create a line style like this, or know of any packages that do something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my try, I use `quiver` to draw the triangles, it need the normal vectors of the line:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

dx = np.diff(x)
dy = np.diff(y)

x2 = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 10)
y2 = np.sin(x2)

dx = np.zeros_like(x2) + 1e-12
dy = np.sin(x2+dx) - y2

length = np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
dx /= length
dy /= length

fig, ax = pl.subplots()
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.plot(x, y, lw=4)

size = 20
ax.quiver(x2, y2, -dy, dx, headaxislength=size, headlength=size, headwidth=size, color="blue")
pl.margins(0.2)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good option! I have rougher lines to draw on, so it's a bit rough, but it works! Thanks!